# SBT scalariform plugin formatting same thing more than once, is it possible do it once?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalariform

[SBT scalariform plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalariform) is formatting files more than once in multi project setup. Here is example https://github.com/Seetaramayya/sbt-scalariform-example

if you compile the project you can see something like this in the console

```
[info] Formatting 5 Scala sources ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/seeta/projects/github/sbt-multi-scalariform/example/"), "root")(compile) ...
[info] Formatting 7 Scala sources ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/seeta/projects/github/sbt-multi-scalariform/example/"), "module1")(compile) ...
[info] Formatting 7 Scala sources ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/seeta/projects/github/sbt-multi-scalariform/example/"), "module2")(compile) ...
[info] Formatting 7 Scala sources ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/seeta/projects/github/sbt-multi-scalariform/example/"), "main")(compile) ...
```

There are 5 scala files and 2 sbt files exist in the code base. Neither in SBT nor in scalariform documentation I could not find how to execute the task only once in multi module setup.

I would like to execute the task only once. Only option I see is enable plugin at root project level and disable at sub-projects but I did not like the option (I need to add `disablePlugins` in `15` sub-projects)

Answer (score 1):

The [issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalariform/issues/73) seems to be that

> Each subproject's `scalariformFormat` task in their different scopes
>   have the project root in their `sourceDirectories` setting. This just
>   leads to the whole project being crawled for scala sources and
>   formatted as many times as there are subprojects.

and has been [addressed](https://github.com/godenji/sbt-scalariform/commit/566475194f217ca69a879674e2efb3d1bde6bfd1) via [`scalariformWithBaseDirectory`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalariform/blob/b33f32b43bd267a3b5e2b26a5962a77182709f52/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/SbtScalariform.scala#L39) setting

```
val scalariformWithBaseDirectory = settingKey[Boolean]("Whether or not to format sources in project root (default: false)")
```

Thus setting `withBaseDirectory=false` in `.scalariform.conf` should give output

```
[info] Formatting 1 Scala source ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/sbt-scalariform-example/"), "main")(compile) ...
[info] Formatting 1 Scala source ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/sbt-scalariform-example/"), "module1")(compile) ...
[info] Formatting 1 Scala source ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/sbt-scalariform-example/"), "module2")(compile) ...
```

Note, however, this will not format `*.scala` sources in the root `project/` directory. To address that we could try keeping `withBaseDirectory=false` in `.conf` but switch it on for the root project like so

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(module1, module2, main)
  .settings(scalariformWithBaseDirectory := true)
```

which outputs

```
[info] Formatting 1 Scala source ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/sbt-scalariform-example/"), "module2")(compile) ...
[info] Formatting 1 Scala source ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/sbt-scalariform-example/"), "module1")(compile) ...
[info] Formatting 1 Scala source ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/sbt-scalariform-example/"), "main")(compile) ...
[info] Formatting 5 Scala sources ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/sbt-scalariform-example/"), "root")(compile) ...
```

where we still get duplication but not as much as initially.